# show gallery div when website load completely otherwise only gallery show loading icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a website and inside website I have a `<div id="gallery">` that have 10 images. I want the website to load immediately, but gallery should show a loading icon until all the images on the website finish loading. And the gallery should be visible after all the images are loaded

It's all like https://www.udemy.com/.

I already tried this code, but this is not working:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('.loader').fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: Did you try using $("#gallery").load instead of $(window).load ?

Comment: yes, i already tried

Comment: you can try 'lazyload' scripts like https://github.com/verlok/lazyload

Answer (score 0):

Try Images loaded plugin [imagesLoaded plugin](https://imagesloaded.desandro.com/). And then

```
$(your gallery div).imagesLoaded(function() {
    $('.preloader').fadeOut(1000);
});
```

Comment: where did u see they use that method

Comment: did u try my method ?

Comment: may be u need to show your html snippet on codepen or jsfiddle so we can see how you are doing it.